# Python: MySQL issue

Tags: python, mysql

I have an issue trying to get data from a MySQL Database. I use the following code:

```
# prepare a cursor object using cursor() method
cursor = db.cursor()

# Prepare SQL query to INSERT a record into the database.
sql = "SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_TYPE='BASE TABLE'"
cursor.execute(sql)
cursor.execute("SHOW TABLES")
tables = cursor.fetchall()

#convert to dataframe and filter
tables_dataframe = pd.DataFrame(list(tables), columns=["Tables"])


tables_dataframe_data = tables_dataframe[tables_dataframe['Tables'].str.startswith("info")]


for i in range(len(tables_dataframe_data)):
    current_data = tables_dataframe_data.iloc[i-1].astype(str).values[0]
    print(current_data)    
    sql2 = "SELECT * FROM " + str(current_data) 
    cursor.execute(sql2)
    current_data_all = cursor.fetchall()
    current_data_all_dataframe = pd.DataFrame(list(current_data_all ))
```

I get the following error at

```
cursor.execute(sql2)
```

pymysql.err.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '-material' at line 1")

current_data = info-material : is a table name and exists

Could it be that "-" is an issue? Is there a way around it?

Comment: So show us `current_data`

Comment: it is a table with the name "info_material" in the database, the code also finds that table as it fetchs first all table names and should then iterate through it

Comment: please put what is in sql2 variable don't execute just the values you are generating.

Comment: Hi Madhy, for example SELECT * FROM info_material-10_1_03

Comment: @Rolf12 column names can't contain hyphens (aka dashes)

Comment: Thanks dan-klasson, this a tablename not a column and the table name exists in the MySQL database already.